# How do I delete an AUR package that shares its name with a Core/Community/Extra package?

Tags: arch-linux, manjaro, pacman, aur

I have redundant packages installed that share the same name on the official repo and AUR.

```
community/nerd-fonts-noto-sans-mono 2.0.0-1 [installed]
community/nerd-fonts-terminus 2.1.0-4 [installed]
aur/nerd-fonts-noto-sans-mono 2.1.0-1 (2, 0.806870) [installed: 2.0.0-1]
aur/nerd-fonts-terminus 2.1.0-4 (9, 0.937352) [installed: 2.1.0-4]
```

How do I remove the AUR packages? If there were no dependencies, I'd remove them all and reinstall, but that's not the case:

```
$ pacaur -Ra nerd-fonts-terminus nerd-fonts-noto-sans-mono

checking dependencies...
error: failed to prepare transaction (could not satisfy dependencies)
:: removing nerd-fonts-terminus breaks dependency 'nerd-fonts-terminus' required by manjaro-i3-settings
:: removing nerd-fonts-noto-sans-mono breaks dependency 'nerd-fonts-noto-sans-mono' required by manjaro-zsh-config
```

I tried the `-a` tag to specify the AUR packages, but I can't tell from the output which packages it thinks it's working on. I believe the dependency requirements link back to the community packges, as suggested by the versions here:

```
$ pacaur -Qd nerd-fonts-terminus nerd-fonts-noto-sans-mono

nerd-fonts-terminus 2.1.0-4
nerd-fonts-noto-sans-mono 2.0.0-1
```

Any advice on how to safely remove the AUR packages?

Comment: It doesn't look like you have the AUR versions installed. Look at the version numbers next to the `installed`, they're of the community repo

Comment: @muru Oh I see. Weird that it highlights the installed flag on those, but I get what you mean. That clears things up, thanks.